# Not able to send data from socket to specific client

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am sending data to a specific client with a socket but on client-side, I am not able to get data.

I'm sending data at this line

```
io.to("user1@example.com").emit('new_msg', {msg: 'hello'});
```

and receive on client with this code

```
socket.on("new_msg", function(data) {
    console.log("here")
    alert(data.msg);
   })
```

Here is my full code, JS and HTML file.

**JS:**

```
var io = require('socket.io')();


io.sockets.on('connection', function(client) {
    console.log('Client connected...', client.id);

    client.on('join', function(data) {
            console.log(data.email);
    });

    client.on('messages', function(data) {
        client.emit('broad', data);
        io.to("user1@example.com").emit('new_msg', {msg: 'hello'});
    });

})

io.listen(3000);
```

**HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <div id="future"></div>
        <form id="form" id="chat_form">
            <input id="chat_input" type="text">
            <input type="submit" value="Send">
        </form>
         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.dev.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>

<script>
 var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:3000');
 socket.on('connect', function(data) {
    socket.emit('join', {email: "user1@example.com"});
 });

  socket.on('broad', function(data) {
         $('#future').append(data+ "<br/>");
   });

  socket.on("new_msg", function(data) {
    console.log("here")
    alert(data.msg);
   })

 $('form').submit(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var message = $('#chat_input').val();
     socket.emit('messages', {email: "user1@example.com"});
 });
</script>
```

I also get a connection success message and also get data from client to server 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you never joined the room and you are emitting the message to that room here

```
 io.to("user1@example.com").emit('new_msg', {msg: 'hello'});
```

Inside join method let the client join the room

```
client.on('join', function(data) {
        console.log(data.email);
       client.join(data.email)
});
```